# C++: write a double approximation in ofstream file, like printf("%f....)

Tags: c++, math, double, ofstream, cmath

I have this problem. I get the result from the function `double sin(double x)`of the library cmath. I want to write this result in a file declared as `ofstream file`and I want that when the result is close to zero, write `0.000000` and not `1.22465e-16`.
For example, I tried:

```
`double x=sin(interval*c);
 file<<"value:"<<x;
 printf("value:%f",x);`
```

where the multiplication between `interval`and `c` is about π.

But in the file is written`1.22465e-16`, while in the shell is written `0.000000`. How can i do to get the approximation`0.000000` in ofstream file? Thanks all

Comment: read this: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/iomanip.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the same format the `"%f"` specifier uses (rather than the default which is `"%g"`), you'd use

```
std::cout << std::fixed;
```

To restore the original format, i.e., get back to using the same format as `"%g"` you'd use

```
std::cout << std::defaultfloat; // C++11
std::cout.setf(std::ios_base::fmtflags(), std::ios_base::floatfield); // pre C++11
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if it is below a threshold and just set it to 0

```
 if(fabs(x) < 1e-8) x = 0;
```

Comment: The reason why somebody else downvoted this is presumably that you forgot to use `fabs`. Because half of the time `sin()` is negative. You meant to write `if(fabs(x) < 1e-8)`

Comment: Or the fact that you're changing the _data_ instead of how it's _displayed_